# Does Rails rake db:migrate needs a javascript runtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, javascript

In my first rails project (using mysql) I tried to execute the `rake db:create` command, but it outputted the following error:

> Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See
>   https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available
>   runtimes.

So I included `gem 'therubyracer', require: "v8"` on my Gemfile and executed a `bundle install`. The problem is solved, but it left some doubts.

Could somebody give me an explanation about why a javascript runtime is needed for this kind of task? I'm new to Ruby and RoR so this seems quite strange to me, why do RoR use javascript for creating a database?

Comment: What library did raise that error? Try again without the rubyracer and with `rake db:create --trace`

Comment: probably coffee-rails and uglifier

Comment: That's it @Ben, coffee-rails was causing the dependency!

Comment: Thanks @tass, didn't know about the --trace parameter

Comment: +1 for asking this question as i faced same problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a javascript runtime because now Rails uses an [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). Rails doesn't need it to run your migrations but when you run `rake db:migrate`, the rake task loads your rails application that needs a javascript runtime to start. Practically, there is no relation between the migrations and the javascript runtime but your app won't load without it.

Comment: Ohh, now I see. That was being caused by the coffee-rails bundle, not the rake utils. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2):

This is for serverside executed javascript. It is used by NodeJS, Coffeescript and quite a few more javascript gems. If you dont use any of those, you can just remove them from your gemfile and no runtime will be required.